Errors while trying to wipe all my disks and reinstall Win 11 Pro
As indicated in the title, my ultimate goal is to have a completely clean install with all my disks erased. I currently have Win 11 Pro installed via upgrade from Win 10 Home. I have a product key.
Method 1 attempt: Use the installer in the image provided on an official Microsoft Windows installation USB thumb drive.
Result: Fails immediately after inputting the product key falsely claiming the system does not meet minimum requirements for the product. (Falsely because it is already installed, and, in fact, I am writing this message within said successful install.)
Method 2 attempt: Create a fresh USB thumb drive using the Microsoft installation media creation utility with the latest image and install from that.
Result: same failure mode as above
Method 3 attempt: Use the "Reset My PC" utility in system settings
Result: Fail. Once it reboots, there's just a window that says "There was a problem when resetting your PC. No changes were made." I cannot find any logs documenting the specific error. The event viewer recorded a critical error from ResetEng with only the text "Attempt to reset the system has failed. Changes to the system have been undone."
Method 4-10 attempt: chkdsk all the disks: disks are fine, no bad sectors, any file system issues have been repaired. Run sfc /scannow--no integrity violations. Run dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth with no issues. Try Reset My PC again. Both locally and from cloud. Both with deleting all disks and just the windows disk.
Result: same failure mode as above.
My random searches have failed to uncover any further approaches. This should not be so difficult. If anyone can think of anything else I can try before I have to actually start spending money, I would be grateful.
For example, is there a way I can find out from the USB installer exactly what issue it thinks this computer has? Microsoft's "PC Health Check" app says, as expected, that the computer does meet product requirements, and that's the only tool I know of that goes into detail about what is lacking.

Do not enter any product key. Activation will occur automatically with the key already in the firmware, if valid.

Now, if you computer doesn't meet the requirements for Windows 11 it's highly doubtful you have upgraded to it before, at least without using 'hacks'/workarounds.

Use the media creation tool to download the install ISO, then use Rufus to create the install USB from the ISO. Once you click Start, a window will pop up, select the options to disable CPU, TPM, and RAM requirement checks. Reboot to the install USB after and either use the GUI or DiskPart to wipe the partition tables (Shift+F10 to open a terminal)

@ChanganAuto It does meet the requirements. It's only the specific installer that comes on the image for media creation utility that doesn't think it does.

The precedent comment explains how to use a workaround with Rufus. And you do need it because if the official installation media says it doesn't meet the requirements it's because it doesn't, end of story.

You may have previously upgraded via an insider edition (a beta release of sorts) and the requirements may have  changed in the final version. The point is you now need to use workarounds as explained in the comment above. And, again, do not enter any product key.

@ChanganAuto no, i didn't use any hacks or beta versions. I used windows update to do this upgrade using the latest versions just a few days ago. again, the PC Health Check app said and says it meets requirements. it is only the windows installer on the disk that is wrong. I am attempting to do the install using the Rufus workaround now, although I'm a bit unclear on the details. We'll see how it goes.

It's important to point out that chkdsk does not identify disk failure, it only detects file system issues, chkdsk has limited uses. Just because you are running Windows 11 does not mean you are running it on supported hardware. The bypass methods to install Windows 11 24H2 and earlier on unsupported hardware on newest builds of the Insider Preview no longer work.

@ChanganAuto the Rufus method worked fine exactly as you and JW0914 described it. all good now.

A method of quickly removing checks is to add the following script to your Windows 11 USB installer under the name bypasscheck.cmd. You can download this file from this GitHub Gist.
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%x in (TPM SecureBoot CPU RAM Storage Disk) do (
  echo.
  set /P a="Bypass %%x check? (Y,[N])> "
  if /I !a!==Y ( 
    echo ^>reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\LabConfig" /v Bypass%%xCheck /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
    reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\LabConfig" /v Bypass%%xCheck /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
  )
)

The checks that can be bypassed are described in the linked article given in DrMoishe Pippik's answer.
An example of this scripts use is given below. Here, only the TPM and Secure Boot checks are removed.
Start the install of Windows 11. When the following screen appears, press shift+F10 to open a Command Prompt window.

Below is example output from using bypasscheck.cmd.
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2861]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

X:\sources>echo list vol | diskpart

Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.22621.1

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: MINWINPC

DISKPART>
  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     E                       CD-ROM          0 B  No Media
  Volume 1     C                NTFS   Partition    179 GB  Healthy
  Volume 2                      FAT32  Partition    100 MB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 3                      NTFS   Partition    768 MB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 4     D   CCCOMA_X64F  NTFS   Partition   8189 MB  Healthy
  Volume 5         UEFI_NTFS    FAT    Partition   1039 KB  Healthy

DISKPART>
X:\sources>d:\bypasscheck

Bypass TPM check? (Y,[N])> y
>reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\LabConfig" /v BypassTPMCheck /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
The operation completed successfully.

Bypass SecureBoot check? (Y,[N])> y
>reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\LabConfig" /v BypassSecureBootCheck /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
The operation completed successfully.

Bypass CPU check? (Y,[N])> n

Bypass RAM check? (Y,[N])> n

Bypass Storage check? (Y,[N])> n

Bypass Disk check? (Y,[N])> n

X:\sources>exit

After the Command Prompt window closes, proceed with the installation Windows 11.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Martin Brinkmann states: "Over the weekend [17-18 Aug 2024], there has been quite a bit of panic about Microsoft blocking one of the ways to install Windows 11 on unsupported hardware."
"Up until now, Microsoft has not enforced hardware requirements. You could install Windows 11 on an unsupported PC and it would run fine. This changes with the release of Windows 11, version 24H2.
Microsoft is enforcing a CPU requirement. The processor needs to support SSE4.2 to run the new version of Windows. This feature is supported by the majority of PCs, as it was introduced around 2008."
"Still, users who have installed Windows 11 on a PC that does not support it cannot upgrade their devices to the new version of Windows 11 or install it from scratch."
"This does not necessarily mean that the PC is incompatible. Sometimes, certain requirements may be disabled. This can be the case for TPM 2.0, Trusted Platform Module."

Therefore, be sure TPM and other needed options are turned on in BIOS.
Check that there is sufficient drive space. (Though if the drive has already been  made free space, totally unallocated, that should not be an issue.)


Only 24H2 to my knowledge has the SSE4.2 requirement, but any processor that does not support SSE4.2, would already fall into a system that does not support Windows 11.
